# can't acess the string

Tags: arrays, c, string

NOTE: I'm doing an exercise where I can't declare and initialize in the same line nor use do-whiles or fors (just whiles).

I'm trying to implement a base conversion algorithm that many of you have probably already seen, but I'm having a hard time as I always get EXC_BAD_ACCESS/KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE

I know this has something to do with hardcoded strings in c but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My code:

```
#include <unistd.h> //read
#include <stdio.h> //printf

#ifndef MAXBUF
# define MAXBUF 16
#endif

int main(void)
{
    char        *buffer[MAXBUF];
    int         p;
    char        *xdigs;
    int         number;
    int         base;

    p = MAXBUF-1;
    xdigs = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("Base: ");
    scanf("%d", &base);
    if (number == 0)
        *buffer[p--] = xdigs[number % base];
    while (number != 0)
    {
        *buffer[p--] = xdigs[number % base];
        number /= base;
    }
    while (buffer[++p] != buffer[MAXBUF-1])
        putchar(*buffer[p]);
    return (0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `char *buffer[MAXBUF];` is an array of pointers, right? Now, what do these pointers point to? What does it mean to dereference one of these pointers like `*buffer[p--]`?

Comment: Did you intend there to be a *single buffer* `char buffer[MAXBUF];` ? And I suspect that `while (buffer[++p] != buffer[MAXBUF-1])` should be `while (++p < MAXBUF-1)`. Aside: I also changed the comparison. It is always safer to make a comparison as inclusive as possible *just in case* `p` happens somehow to be the 'wrong side' of `MAXBUF`.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes just one buffer; Oh thank you, I missed that

Comment: @ForceBru Oh damn I left the star there! My bad. Thanks!